# How to implement custom gesture on an ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, gesture

I succeed in implementing a custom gesture at the level of the activity, through the following "standard" code. So the entire screen "reacts" to the gesture.

However I would like to be able to detect my custom gesture when it is done on a specific ImageView. Is it possible?

Thanks

```
public class DisplayMultiImageActivity extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener {

    GestureLibrary mLibrary;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_multiimage);

        mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
        if (!mLibrary.load()) {
            finish();
        }

        GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
        gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
        if (predictions.size() > 0 && predictions.get(0).score > 1.0) {
            String result = predictions.get(0).name;

            if ("mycustomgesture".equalsIgnoreCase(result)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Custom gesture detected!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your XML-file, the `GestureOverlayView` probably takes up the whole screen. If you want it to only react on gestures on an ImageView, you should set the `GestureOverlayView` over the `ImageView`.

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/gestures"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
             // attributes of ImageView />

</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

EDIT

The `onGesturePerformedListener` receives the `GestureOverlayView` on which the gesture was performed in the method `onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView, Gesture)`.

In this method, check which `GestureOverlayView` was used, and execute the related action.

So you should set a diferent `GestureOverlayView` on every ImageView you want to track Gestures on.

```
    @Override
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
           switch(overlay.getId()) {
           case (R.id.overlay1):
                \\ DO SOMETHING WITH IMAGEVIEW 1
                break;
           case (R.id.overlay2):
                \\ DO SOMETHING WITH IMAGEVIEW 2
                break;
           case (R.id.overlay3):
                \\ DO SOMETHING WITH IMAGEVIEW 3
                break;
           default:
                \\
           }
     }
```

Comment: Hello Robbe, thanks for your anwser, it works! However I think I didn't explain my entire goal with this custom gesture: I have several images in my Layout and the gesture is going to be used to select one of the image: I therefore would like to know on which image the user has executed the gesture. Do you think it is possible?? Thanks